# Considéré +adjectif contre considéré comme + adjectif

Tags: adjectifs, formulation-idiomatique

- Le mot auparavant est considéré soutenu.
- Le mot auparavant est considéré comme soutenu.

Ces tournures sont-elles, toutes les deux, idiomatiques ?

Sont-elles équivalentes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La deuxième est idiomatique, on peut aussi ajouter *est considéré comme étant soutenu*.

La première est grammaticale mais sonne bizarrement.